# VBA - optimize runtime for hiding columns

Tags: vba, search, optimization

I have a worksheet with a table of 50 years, starting from 2017 to 2066. This macro is making a print area for the first 10 years, with the tenth year being a user input and hiding any other columns. We would remove the 10th consecutive year (2026) and replace it with the user input only if the user input is greater than 2026.

I'm finding that my macro is really slow and I'm looking for feedback on how to speed it up.

```
With Sheet1
  If userinputyear > 2026 Then
    c = 10 'column index corresponding to consecutive 10th year 2026
    Do While .Cells(5, c) <> userinputyear
       .Cells(5, c).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
       c = c + 1
    Loop
    Do While c + 1 <> 50 'column index corresponding to year 2066
      .Cells(5, c + 1).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
       c = c + 1
    Loop
end with
```

Comment: You can start by using `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the top and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks Bernie, I do have it in my macro.

Comment: Skip that last loop and use something like `.Cells(5, c + 1).Resize(1,50-c).EntireColumn.Hidden = True`

Comment: What's with the code lines commented out, are they actually part of the slow macro or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this go faster? (supposes your columns are sorted based on the year)

```
With Sheet1
    If userInputYear > 2026 Then
        .Cells(1, 10).Resize(, 41).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        .Columns(userInputYear - 2016).Hidden = False
    End If
End With
```

Comment: So hide all columns after the 10th year and beyond, then unhide the userinput?

Comment: @excelmonkey93 if the columns are sorted per year, yeah, why not?

Comment: brilliant, didn't think of that.. thanks lol. what's a good way of testing runtime?

Comment: By doing some tests with big data, or actual copies of your real data, worst case expected size... I think you shouldn't be satisfied if this operation is not almost instantaneous.

Comment: question on resize. in your code, it's resizing (hides) the next 41 columns, including the 10th column?

Comment: yep, columns 10 to 50, that counts 41 columns.

Comment: got it. thanks again man, you're always answering my questions, appreciate it!

Comment: @excelmonkey93 you're welcome. I also appreciate your way of asking and following up :)